# Access a ListView item when Clicked

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin.Android proyect, I am filling a list view with a Web Service query. Now I need to access the listview's items values which I will use for future queries.
This is how I fill my listView

```cs
 WebReference.ToDoWS cliente = new ToDoWS();
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            tabla = cliente.ObtenerTareas();
            ListView listado = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.tareas);
            if (tabla.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                List<string> tareas = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    tareas.Add(tabla.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<string> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, tareas);
                listado.Adapter = adaptador;
            }
```

Here's a pick of how it looks

[image: android picture]

Is there a way to access the text values inside each row? I tried with the `SetOnClickListener` but I don't know how to use it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the item index with the following:

```cs
 listado.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                string index = e.Position.ToString();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Click" + index, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            };
```

Documentation Referece: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/api-design#Events_and_Listeners

Comment: Could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who has similar question could get help from your answer?

Comment: Yeah sorry, couldn't accept my own answer after two days